# Insert date field value into a varcharfield plus additional hardcoded text

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I would like to do an update to a varchar field, updating it to be the Date value (formatted in MM/DD/YYYY format) from another date field, as well as hardcoded text. It would be something along these lines, where the column EFFDT is a datetime field, and DESCRIPTION is a varchar field:

```
UPDATE R 
SET R.DESCRIPTION = 'Account Inactivated on: " + P.EFFDT 
FROM dbo.ProductReviews AS R
INNER JOIN dbo.products AS P 
       ON R.pid = P.id 
WHERE R.id = 'A0358'
```

Example of the result would be:

```
DESCRIPTION
Account Inactivated on 07/05/2018
```

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
UPDATE R 
    SET R.DESCRIPTION = 'Account Inactivated on: ' + FORMAT(P.EFFDT, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
    FROM dbo.ProductReviews R INNER JOIN
         dbo.products P 
         ON R.pid = P.id 
    WHERE R.id = 'A0358';
```